# pythagorean theorem extensions

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

are there for a given integer N solutions to the equations

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{N}x_{i} ^{2}=z^{2} $$

for integers $ x_i $ and $ z$

an easier equation given an integer number 'a' can be there solutions to the equation

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{N}x_{i} ^{2}=a^2 $$

for N=2 this is pythagorean theorem

Comment: You might be interested in Gauss's work on the sum of 4 squares, relatively little was known about the sum of 3 squares when I was learning about it a few years ago (but there are a few results) and the case of 2 is solved - I believe it is called the Chirstmas problem? (Essentially, if and only if the squarefree part of $a$ has no prime factors of the form $4k + 3$.)

Comment: Unless I completely misunderstood the problem... EDIT: I did misunderstand, I was solving $\sum x_i^2 = a$. But surely there are always solutions (namely, $(x_1,\dots,x_N) = (a, 0, \dots, 0)$?)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_quadruple

Comment: You can bootstrap $a^2 + b^2 = c^2 \implies a^2a^2 + a^2b^2 + b^2c^2 = a^2c^2 + b^2c^2 = c^2c^2$ so there will be solution for all n by induction.  These don't feel like "basic" solutions as the are derived from 2-d bootstrapped.  But I don't know how to rephrase the question in more specific terms to eliminate these.

Comment: All n will have solutions by bootstrapping.  $a^2 + b^2 = c^2\implies (a^2)^2 + (ab)^2 + (bc)^2 = (c^2)^4$ seems trivial we also have $3,4,5$ and $5,12,13$ lead to $3^2 + 4^2 + 12^3=13^2$.  I think the real question how do we generalize solutions and are there any solutions for n that are not bootstrapped for lower n.  I don't know how to proceed but I strongly suspect no.  We can generalize the bootstraps by generalizing the n=2 solutions (which are $[k(2m+1)]^2 + [k(2m^2 + 2m)]^2 = [k(2m^2+2m+1)]^2)$

Comment: oh.... obviously $\sum_{k=1}^{N^2} 1^2 = N^2$ isn't bootstrapped from any $n < N^2$.  But between bootstrapping from i)1+1+...+1=n^2, ii)$\sum x^2 = y^2\implies \sum (kx)^2 = (ky)^2$ iii) $\sum x^2 = y^2;\sum z^2 =x_i^2\implies \sum z^2 + \sum x_{\overline i}^2 = y^2$ and iv) $(2m+1)^4 + (2m^2 + 2m)^2 = (2m^2 + 2m + 1)^2$, I strongly suspect we have a basis for all solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to avoid notation bloat, let's let $N=4$ and let the implied generalization take care of the rest of the question. The question can be restated as asking whether there are rational points on the $4$-sphere $\mathbb S_4:x_1^2 + x_2^2 +x_3^2+x_4^2=1$. We know that $(1,0,0,0)$ is a (trivial) rational point on 
$\mathbb S_4$. From that point, we pick a rational direction, 
$(\xi_1, \xi_2, \xi_3, \xi_4)$ where $\xi_1, \xi_2, \xi_3, \xi_4$ are rational numbers, and see if the line $(1,0,0,0)+t(\xi_1, \xi_2, \xi_3, \xi_4)$ intersects
$\mathbb S_4$ at another rational point.

\begin{align}
   (1+t\xi_1)^2 + t^2 \xi_2^2 + t^2 \xi_3^2 + t^2 \xi_4^1 &= 1 \\
   2t\xi_1 + t^2(\xi_1^2 + \xi_2^2 + \xi_3^2 + \xi_4^2) &= 0 \\
   t &= -\dfrac{2\xi_1}{\xi_1^2 + \xi_2^2 + \xi_3^2 + \xi_4^2} 
\end{align}

So, for any four rational numbers $\xi_1, \xi_2, \xi_3, \xi_4$

$$\left(
   \dfrac{-\xi_1^2 + \xi_2^2 + \xi_3^2 + \xi_4^2}
      {\xi_1^2 + \xi_2^2 + \xi_3^2 + \xi_4^2}, 
   -\dfrac{2\xi_1 \xi_2}{\xi_1^2 + \xi_2^2 + \xi_3^2 + \xi_4^2},
   -\dfrac{2\xi_1 \xi_3}{\xi_1^2 + \xi_2^2 + \xi_3^2 + \xi_4^2},
   -\dfrac{2\xi_1 \xi_4}{\xi_1^2 + \xi_2^2 + \xi_3^2 + \xi_4^2},
\right)$$

is a rational point on $\mathbb S_4$